# How to match the same cards in two arrays

Tags: arrays, xcode, swift

I'm creating a snap game were the player has to match two cards. I've created two arrays one for english cards and one for Spanish cards.The pack generates random cards but I can't get the same cards matching, which the player wins 1 point when the cards are correctly matched.

```
 var cardNamesArray: [String] = ["sad", "sleepy","angry"]
 var cardNamesArray2: [String] = ["triste", "cansado","enfadado"]

    //first card generate random number
    let firstRandomNumber = Int (arc4random_uniform(3))
    let firstCardString:String = self.cardNamesArray[firstRandomNumber]
    self.FirstCardImageView.image = UIImage(named: firstCardString)

    //Second Card generate random number
    let SecondRandomNumber = Int (arc4random_uniform(3))
    let SecondCardString:String = self.cardNamesArray2[SecondRandomNumber]
    self.SecondCardImageView.image = UIImage(named: SecondCardString)
```

I tried matching "sad" with "triste" but the score remains the same

```
        if ["sad"] == ["triste"] {

        print("match")

        self.playerScore += 1
        self.playerScoreLabel.text = String(self.playerScore)

    }
```

Comment: Since Xcode isn't a simultaneous interpreter, compare the numbers (array indexes)  `if firstRandomNumber == secondRandomNumber`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least two different ways to do it, depending on how distant you are from the random number generation:

If you still have the random numbers available, you can use:

```
if firstRandomNumber == secondRandomNumber {
    print("number match")
}
```

If you don't still have the random numbers available, but just have the strings, you can use `indexOf` to find the string in the appropriate array:

```
if cardNamesArray.indexOf(firstCardString) == cardNamesArray2.indexOf(secondCardString) {
    print("index match")
}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. What about when the cards are matched they are cleared so they don't re-appear again